# What is meaning of (qs | qs1) in the code below?

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie in Django. What is the overall logic in the code below? And still what does (qs | qs1) really mean in Python/Django?

```
class TweetDetailAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Tweet.objects.all()
    serializer_class  = TweetModelSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsPagination
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tweet_id = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        qs = Tweet.objects.filter(pk=tweet_id)
        if qs.exists() and qs.count() == 1:
            parent_obj = qs.first()
            qs1 = parent_obj.get_children()
            qs = (qs | qs1).distinct().extra(select={"parent_id_null": 'parent_id IS NULL'})
        return qs.order_by("parent_id_null", '-timestamp')
```

```
        the_parent = self
        if self.parent:
            the_parent = self.parent
        return the_parent

    def get_children(self):
        parent = self.get_parent()
        qs = Tweet.object.filter(parent=parent)
        qs_parent = Tweet.objects.filter(pk.parent.pk)
        return (qs | qs_parent)
```

Comment: PS: The first block of code id part of my views.py and the second one is part of my models.py

Comment: @Frechz Please edit your question with your P.S comment. And it is a logical `OR` operation.

Answer (score 1):

It's an OR operation between two querysets. Look into [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#or) for more info.